# Getting an NSwindow from Air extension

Tags: macos, air

Is there a way to get an NSWindow reference from its id from an AIR extension?

I am making an Adobe Air app which is supposed to stay always on top. It is for kids so you can give a computer to them and they can't exit the app. The problem is that the default "alwaysOnTop" property of air applications doesn't work. What I am planning to do is use a native extension to get the Air window id and then try and set the level. I've already checked with the accessibility API but apparently there is no way of doing it that way. I could be wrong, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way. Just use the global NSapp variable to get the main window from inside an Air native extension. Then call setLevel on that window and that's it.